# ITK wrapper for integration into c#- unresolved external symbol

Tags: c#, itk

I have developed an application using itk and I am trying to integrate it with c#.I have written a wrapper ,in the wrapper application I have included all ITK .libs in the linker input tab.I am still getting unresolved external errors. These are the errors which I am getting:

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__UuidCreate@4 referenced in function "protected: static bool __cdecl gdcm::UIDGenerator::GenerateUUID(unsigned char *)" (?GenerateUUID@UIDGenerator@gdcm@@KA_NPAE@Z) \ObliquePlaneWrapper\itkgdcmMSFF-4.9.lib(gdcmUIDGenerator.obj) ObliquePlaneWrapper

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gethostname@8 referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl gdcm::System::GetHostName(char * const)" (?GetHostName@System@gdcm@@SA_NQAD@Z) \ObliquePlaneWrapper\itkgdcmCommon-4.9.lib(gdcmSystem.obj)  ObliquePlaneWrapper

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSACleanup@0 referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl gdcm::System::GetHostName(char * const)" (?GetHostName@System@gdcm@@SA_NQAD@Z) \ObliquePlaneWrapper\itkgdcmCommon-4.9.lib(gdcmSystem.obj)   ObliquePlaneWrapper

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSAStartup@8 referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl gdcm::System::GetHostName(char * const)" (?GetHostName@System@gdcm@@SA_NQAD@Z) \ObliquePlaneWrapper\itkgdcmCommon-4.9.lib(gdcmSystem.obj)   ObliquePlaneWrapper

How do i fix these errors? 
-swetha

Comment: Missing `ws2_32` link AFAIK

Comment: Hi @swetha, so I have spent the last weeks trying to do this. Can you please share how you created a managed dll with itk for use in c# ? I really want to integrate ITK in my c# project but have limited c++ knowledge in creating the wrappers. SimpleITK is considered but does not meet my requirements. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used CMAKE instead of adding the .lib files manually.It solved my problem